# Test class 0% I wonder why its not covering code

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
trigger test on p__c (before delete) {
if(Trigger.size == 1)
{
    try
    {
        p__c pt = [Select id, (Select id from c__r), (Select id from t__r) from p__c where id = :Trigger.old[0].id];
        Boolean dep = false;
        List<String> objList = new List<String>();   

        if(pt.c__r.size() > 0)
        {
            objList.add('c');
            dep  = true;
        }
        if(pt.t__r.size() > 0)
        {
            objList.add('t');
            dep  = true;
        }

        if(dep)
        {
            String err = 'Please delete the related "'+objList[0];
            if(objList.size()>1)
            {
                err += '" and "'+objList[1]+'" recordsList';
            }
            else
                err += '" ';
            Trigger.old[0].addError(err);
        }
    }
    catch(QueryException e) 
    {
        Trigger.old[0].addError('delete record');
    }
}
}
```

**Test Class**

```
    @isTest
public class testTest
{
    public static testMethod void unitTestMethod()
    {
        Test.StartTest();
        Account parentAccount = new Account();
        parentAccount.Name = 'SunMicro Group';
        insert parentAccount;

        String recdTypeId = [Select id From RecordType Where SobjectType = 'Account' And Name = 'p'].Id;
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'AIS Group';
        acc.RecordTypeId = recdTypeId;
        acc.ParentId = parentAccount.id;
        insert acc; 

        f__c f = new f__c();
        f.Name = 'M f';
        f.f_Type__c = 'f';
        f.I_C__c = 'f';
        insert f;

        p__c p = new p__c();
        p.Name = 'AIS';
        p.f__c = f.id;
        insert p;

        c__c cmt = new c__c();
        cmt.L_P__c = acc.id;
        cmt.p__c = p.id;
        insert cmt;

        Test.StopTest();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide your test class as well?

Comment: You may run out of letters with that naming convention. I can here your support team crying now -  "I am trying to insert a record into **p** and **z** is giving me a validation error. I tried to update **a** but **c** would not let me. Do i need to update **y** first, not sure cause I know the **aa** is set properly?".

Comment: @Eric You never know. Maybe they were going for an obfuscation badge?

Comment: @sfdcfox you made me look. I could not find one lol

Answer (score 3):

That's because your trigger is before delete and you there is no delete in your test method. At least you need to delete some P...

Okay, and you really, really need to change your name conventions. @Eric, your comment made my day.

Answer (score 2):

First, your code is incredibly complex. Here's a basic reduced form:

```
trigger test on p__c (before delete) {
    Set<Id> p_c = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT p__c Id from c__c where p__c in :trigger.old group by p__c]).keySet(),
            p_t = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT p__c Id from t__c where p__c in :trigger.old group by p__c]).keySet();
    for(p__c p: trigger.old) {
        String[] o = new String[0];
        if(p_c.contains(p.id)) {
            o.add('c');
        }
        if(p_t.contains(p.id)) {
            o.add('t');
        }
        if(!o.isEmpty()) {
            p.addError('Please delete the related '+String.join(o,' and ')+' records.');
        }
    }
}
```

From there, make sure you actually delete your record to test:

```
Database.DeleteResult dr = Database.delete(p, false);
System.assertEquals(false, dr.isSuccess());
```